# What is the recommended gitattributes settings?

Tags: git

What is the recommended gitattributes settings for the following files:

- .user
- .suo
- .cache
- .application
- .asax
- .manifest

It's a C# repo under windows OS.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If you set Git as your version control system, VS might generate a `.gitattributes` file for you.

Comment: [A collection of useful .gitattributes templates - Github repo](https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `.application`, `.asax`, and `.manifest` files, but for `.user`, `.suo`, and `.cache` files, GitHub recommends ignoring those files in `.gitignore`. If they're ignored, then you shouldn't need to worry about configurations for them in `.gitattributes`, since, well, they won't be included in your repo.

The following are lines from the standard GitHub `.gitignore` for C# projects:

```
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user

# Others
*.Cache
```